# Linear Algebra II - Orthogonal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

If $X = [1,-2, 1, 6]$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and let $U = span \{[2,1,3,-4], [1,2,0, 1]\}$.

 How would you show that $\{[1,0,2,-3], [4,7,1,2]\}$ is another orthogonal basis of $U$.

Would I be able to simply go ahead by constructing if the second set of vectors is orthogonal by using $\{E1,E2\}$? Or would i have to incorporate $U$ somehow?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: I just don't know whether if I can simply go ahead and use E1 = X1 then E2 = X2-X2 x E1 etc or if I have to include U somehow into the equation?

Comment: This isn't a question. Make sure to state what parts of the question you do and don't understand. Note that X isn't related to U.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please consider learning typesetting with LaTeX or MathJax and if something looks like homework to show any own efforts you've made. These things together go a long way to get good responses and avoid inducing grumpyness.

Comment: What does $X$ have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to show $2$ things:

1) $B = \{[1,0,2,-3], [4,7,1,2]\}$ is a basis for $U$

2) B is an orthogonal set of vectors

Obviously, 2) is the easiest part here since $1*4 + 0*7 + 2*1 + (-3)*2 = 0$, implying that these $2$ vectors are orthogonal.

For 1), one has to prove that:

- These two vectors span $U$
- These two vectors are linear independent

Linear independency should be straightforward to prove (make a linear combination of the two vectors that is equal to $[0,0,0,0]$ and show the scalars must be $0$).

That $U$ is spanned by these 2 vectors might be more difficult, but the easiest way to show this is that you can write $[2,1,3,-4],[1,2,0,1]$ as linear combination of the two given vectors, because then you know $span\{[1,0,2,-3], [4,7,1,2]\} = span\{[2,1,3,-4],[1,2,0,1]\} = U$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** 
Stuff the vectors spanning the spaces into two matrices $$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}2&1&3&-4\\1&2&0&1\end{array}\right], B = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&2&-3\\4&7&1&2\end{array}\right]$$

To show that a basis is orthogonal: show that all basis vectors are pairwise orthogonal to each other. How can you do that with matrix multiplication?

To show they span the same space, search for a matrix $T$ so that $TB = A$

If you manage to solve and find such a $T$ then it is the matrix transforming coordinates form the first basis into the other.